# How to implement onPress in menu.item? native-base@3.2.1-rc.1

Tags: react-native, native-base

For some reason there's no nativeBase api or documentation on this. I can not get a menu.item to respond to press/click no matter what I try.

Attempts

- putting Text/Button elements from react-native into the menu. item
- putting the menu in multiple different screens
- creating a separate function instead of just arrow function

```
import React from "react"
import {
  Menu,
  HamburgerIcon,
  Box,
  Center,
  NativeBaseProvider,
  usePropsResolution,
  Text,
  Pressable
} from "native-base"
import {Alert, } from "react-native";
import { logout } from "../_redux/_actions/authentication.actions";



export const NavMenu = (props) => { 

  const menuItems = ['Profile','Sign Out'];
  

 

return (
  <Box h="80%" w="95%" alignItems="flex-start">
    <Menu w="150" top="-85" h="100%"
      trigger={(triggerProps) => {
        return (
          <Pressable accessibilityLabel="More options menu" {...triggerProps}>
            <HamburgerIcon color="black" />
          </Pressable>
        )
      }}
    >
      
        **<Menu.Item  onPress={()=>alert("Alert Title")}>**
          Logout
        </Menu.Item>
   

    </Menu>
  </Box>
)
}

export default () => {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Center flex={1} px="1">
        <NavMenu />
      </Center>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround around this problem. Would be interested in better solution, but this should work (it is also not very clean solution):

```
<Menu.Item  onPress={()=>alert("Alert Title")}>
    <Pressable onPress={()=>alert("Alert Title")}><Text>Logout</Text></Pressable>
</Menu.Item>
```

Basically what I am doing here is putting *onPress* to the Menu.Item and then same *onPress* to the child. You can use this approach for more complicated situations like adding button to the menu like this:

```
<Menu.Group title="Účet">
   <Menu.Item onPress={() => console.log('log')}>
      <Button colorScheme="red" onPress={() => console.log('log')} leftIcon={<Icon size="s" as={<MaterialIcons name='logout'  />} />}>
         Logout
      </Button>
   </Menu.Item>
</Menu.Group>
```